# Expressions about trash/garbage

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions

I'm a Chinese living in NYC. How do Americans call these things? Are they all named "trash can"?

And If I want to drop something, like an empty bottle, what is the right way to say that? "drop garbage"? "litter" ? "throw away garbage" or else?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these containers called for waste?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521228/what-are-these-containers-called-for-waste)

Comment: They are all *garbage cans* or *trash cans*. In some expressions, they might simply by *the garbage* or *the trash*. The last image borders on being a dumpster -- some people might be less likely to call it a can than a *garbage container* or a *garbage bin* or a *dumpster*. You want to *throw away* your bottle or, more colloquially, perhaps to *toss it*. You could also be said to *put it in the trash*.  Hopefully you would not *litter*--that would be leaving it somewhere it does not belong (like the ground) rather than in an appropriate receptacle.

Comment: I usually say *dispose*

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall Thank you! This is a good explanation!

Comment: @MikeGraham Thank you! If I need to throw away the kitchen garbage for collection, is this also called "toss the garbage"?

Comment: @KeYY When you move a bag of garbage from inside your home to a dumpster or a large garbage can for pickup, that is *taking out the garbage* (or *taking out the trash*).

Comment: @MikeGraham Thank you! That helps a lot.